# Trying to use a while loop to repeatedly scan for a user response in a Discord bot but not working

Tags: python, while-loop, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm working on a dice roll bot for a D&D server I'm in and it's supposed to loop and repeatedly test for a message from the user saying to roll the die or to end the battle, but for some reason it just doesn't work. No error message, no nothing. Anyone know how to fix it?

```
@bot.command()
async def battle(ctx, arg, arg2):
    await ctx.send("**A battle has begun between "+arg+" and "+arg2+"!**")
    await ctx.send("_ _")
    await ctx.send("Would you like to use dice roll mechanics for this battle? [yes/no]")
    @bot.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content == "no" or message.content == "No" or message.content == "NO" or message.content == "n" or message.content == "N":
            await ctx.send("Ok! Pin the battle message to archive this fight and get to RPing!")
        if message.content == "yes" or message.content == "Yes" or message.content == "YES" or message.content == "y" or message.content == "Y":
            await ctx.send("Alright! Whenever your character makes a move or performs an action, say 'roll die' to roll a 20-sided die and see how effective your action was! To end the battle, say 'end battle'!")
            fight = 0
            while fight == 0:
                @bot.event
                async def on_message(message):
                    if message.content == "roll die" or message.content == "ROLL DIE" or message.content == "Roll die" or message.content == "Roll Die":
                        roll = random.randint(1, 20)
                        await ctx.send("You rolled: "+str(roll))
                    if message.content == "end battle" or message.content == "END BATTLE" or message.content == "End battle" or message.conent == "End Battle":
                        await ctx.send("Battle is over! Pin the starting battle message I sent to archive this fight!")
                        fight+=1
```

Comment: Why are you defining a function `on_message()` *inside* a function called `on_message()`? Inside a while loop? And never calling it?

Comment: Check out discord.py's `Client.wait_for()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would greatly advise that you reformat your code to be step-by-step. What this means is that your bot is only looking for a response when it needs one. With your current setup, if you type "no" anywhere at any time, your bot will execute that scenario.

Here's a reformatted version of your code that I think could fit your needs better:

```py
import asyncio
import random

@bot.command()
async def battle(ctx, arg1, arg2):
    await ctx.send(f"**A battle has begun between {arg1} and {arg2}!**")
    await ctx.send("_ _")
    await ctx.send("Would you like to use dice roll mechanics for this battle? [yes/no]")

    def check(message):
        if message.channel != ctx.channel:
            return False

        if message.author != ctx.author:
            return False

        return True

    try:
        response = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        return await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time.")

    if response.content == "no" or response.content == "No" or response.content == "NO" or response.content == "n" or response.content == "N":
        await ctx.send("Ok! Pin the battle message to archive this fight and get to RPing!")
    if response.content == "yes" or response.content == "Yes" or response.content == "YES" or response.content == "y" or response.content == "Y":
        await ctx.send("Alright! Whenever your character makes a move or performs an action, say 'roll die' to roll a 20-sided die and see how effective your action was! To end the battle, say 'end battle'!")
        fight = 0

        while fight == 0:
            try:
                response = await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=30)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                return await ctx.send("You didn't answer in time.")

            if response.content == "roll die" or response.content == "ROLL DIE" or response.content == "Roll die" or response.content == "Roll Die":
                roll = random.randint(1, 20)
                await ctx.send(f"You rolled: {roll}")
            if response.content == "end battle" or response.content == "END BATTLE" or response.content == "End battle" or response.content == "End Battle":
                await ctx.send("Battle is over! Pin the starting battle message I sent to archive this fight!")
                fight += 1
```